# Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine c#

Tags: c#, oledb

I leave it to you because I am totally desperate.

I am using **Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0** to read my excel files, it works fine on my pc but when I put the application on my server (Windows Server 2012 R2) I get The 'Microsoft.Jet error. OLEDB.4.0 'provider is not registered on the local machine.
By doing research on the Internet I could see that the application had to be build correctly compared to the server but nothing helped I tried in *x64* and *x86* and I still have the error (i have also tested **Jet.Oledb.12.0** but still nothing).
there is my code :

```
            if (Path.GetExtension(path).ToUpper() == ".XLS")
            { //&& Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem == false) {
                //Connectionstring for excel v8.0    
                Console.WriteLine("Jet.OLEDB.4.0");
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
            }
            else
            {
                //Connectionstring fo excel v12.0
                Console.WriteLine("Jet.OLEDB.12.0");
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
            }
```

There is my server settings :
[image: ComputerSettings]

There is the installation on the server :

[image]

Do you have an idea ? Thank's in adavance ;)

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/

Answer (score 4):

First, change your connection string from Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0 to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 using [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/) link.

Secondly, install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

It‘s an update for the old Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0 driver and used to make the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 connection string works properly.

Comment: Finally, i had a bug with Visual studio yesterday. Today, if i build my projet in x86, the application work good with Jet.OleDB ! Thank you for your answer ! :D