# Old vb.net application states that OLEDB.40 is not registered on this computer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, oledb

I am updating an older application, for which I had to dig out Visual Studio 2008. The application uses the JET Engine, 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'

It has an interesting flaw - when I work with it, it out of nowhere gives the error that "The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."
Now I have had this so many times, that I know what to do - delete solution and check it out again.
This error is only when running/debugging from Visual Studio. The compiled EXE works all the time

I have checked the folders and tried to just reinstate the database etc etc, but I cannot see what is wrong. Checking updated files by date, there is nothing weird. Only 4 *.vb files. I cannot see any other change.

For some reason it just does not see the OLEDB.40 anymore, but the compiled exe works. Obviously the OLEDB.40 is there, but Visual Studio will not see it.

This error happens at random, from every 10 mins to every 2 days.
Every time I delete the solution and check it out again, and I can work again.

Any ideas?

LATEST: I tried checking the code out to a new place, copying 5 *.vb files and VS2008 can run/debug again.
Checking it out to the original location will not work, nor copying the new  checkout into the old place.
But checking it out in a new place and I am back up again...
The issue is related to the path

Comment: Try this maybe you can solve your problem: [Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0 provider is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63163124/10725496)

Comment: @EduardoEspinosa I googled a bit before I wrote this, and I have tried that. No change

Comment: Strong signs of security software getting in the way.  Temporarily disable it to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yep I agree with Hans as I've had this using VS2008 (loooong time ago). Your location is probably not trusted by windows. Is it on a network drive?

Comment: Nope, ordinary repository folder from git (c:\users....repos...) with the debug and release folders, and a database folder in there. Only the database in the database folder